# Error calling Fedex webservice

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services

from my windows application i am trying to send xml to fedex url and expecting response back from fedex. i am getting error "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error."

what is the meaning of this error and why i am getting this error because the url i got from fedex support people....so i think the service url is right. here i am giving my code by which i am trying to send xml to fedex service url.

```
 public string Post(string sXml)
    {
        string Err = "";
        WebResponse WebRes = null;
        string sResponse = "";
        try
        {
            string URL = "https://gatewaybeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/ship"; // "https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/ship";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sXml);  
            HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);  
            WebReq.Method = "POST";
            WebReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";  
            WebReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
            Stream ReqStream = WebReq.GetRequestStream();
            ReqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            ReqStream.Close();
            WebRes = WebReq.GetResponse();
            Stream ResStream = WebRes.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader ResReader = new StreamReader(ResStream);
            sResponse = ResReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Err = ex.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {

        }
        return sResponse;
    }
```

is there any error in my code. please guide why i am getting error. i am talking to fedex support but not getting any technical help from them.

thanks

Comment: The fact that the word **beta** is in the address is a big red flag for me. It's exactly as the error states - there is a problem at the web service end. You can only get an answer from Fedex tech support, we cannot possibly guess what this may be.

Comment: i tried with this address https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/ship but still have no luck.

Comment: I'm having the same issue,have you been able to solve it ?

Comment: yah i solved long back.i will try to post full code of mine but tell me what problem u r facing. i send xml to fedex web service directly from my c# apps without adding any fedex web service reference.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is from the Fedex server, but the cause of the error is probably in the URL you send their server, probably in the form of illegal arguments. Double check the Fedex URL requirements.

Comment: so tell me what should be the url......i tried with also https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/ship...i got this url from fedex support people.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Plain XML (not SOAP), use:

https://wsbeta.fedex.com/xml

https://ws.fedex.com/xml